# Cannot access some properties from Mongoose document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am doing a query on my database using Mongoose to retrieve all documents in a collection.  Currently there is only one document in the collection.  It returns the document and looks fine, but I cannot access some of the properties.

Code snippet:

```
User.find()
    .then((response)=>{
        console.log(response);
        console.log();
        console.log(response[0]._id);
        console.log(response[0].name);
        console.log(response[0].email);
        console.log(response[0].zipCode);
        console.log(response[0].dateTime);
        console.log(response[0].ipAddr);
        console.log(response[0].pageVisited);
    }).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)});
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    _id: 5f6d4dc312c76000170c5c43,
    name: 'Bob',
    email: 'bob@mail.com',
    zipCode: '12345',
    pageVisited: 'p1m2549',
    dateTime: 2020-09-25T01:54:11.152Z,
    ipAddr: '111.111.111.111',
    __v: 0
  }
]

5f6d4dc312c76000170c5c43
Bob
bob@mail.com
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

What could be causing this bizarre behavior?  It really doesn't make any sense that I can access some of the properties but not others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That could be because these elements not be defined in the Schema

Define Schema as mentioned below

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    zipCode: String,
    pageVisited: String,
    dateTime: Date,
    ipAddr: String,
    __v: Number

  });

var User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema );

User.find()
    .then((response)=>{
        console.log(response);
        console.log();
        console.log(response[0]._id);
        console.log(response[0].name);
        console.log(response[0].email);
        console.log(response[0].zipCode);
        console.log(response[0].dateTime);
        console.log(response[0].ipAddr);
        console.log(response[0].pageVisited);
        console.log(response[0].__v);
    }).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)});
```

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it.  Makes sense.  Out of curiosity, do you know what exactly is happening here?  Why does the response variable, printed as a whole, show the full data.  But when I dig down into the string/object some of the properties are undefined?  That doesn't seem to make sense to me.  I would think that it would just not have that data at all.

Comment: I was just stuck with this issue and I have been searching for this answer the whole time since 1 hour. I'll help with the search queries I was looking to find the solution:

mongoose naming fields as Image with first letter capital
mongoose Image as field key
mongodb can't get value Image field with I capital
mongodb can't get value of field with first letter capital

This will probably help someone land on this page